# Linux Permissions Questions

Tags: linux, permissions

Hey, I'm sure you get these kinds of questions a lot, but despite reading guides on how this should work I'm still stumped.

I have a directory in my home directory that I'd like to share with another user. I created a group developer. I added myself and him to a group, changed the group of the directory recursively, and then recursively gave the directory `g+rwx` permissions.

At this point `id user` returns the name of the group as the primary group, and `ll` prints out the permissions as so:

```
drwsrwxr-x 15 john developer
```

The owner being me, the group being developer, and group permissions being rwx. However, the other user still only has read and execute permissions, leading me to think he's being treated as other.

Any ideas of what I could be doing wrong here? It seems pretty cut and dry and I can't find my error, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe more suitable for http://superuser.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a question with an answer on how to do the exact same thing:
https://serverfault.com/questions/44818/how-do-i-set-up-a-shared-directory-on-linux

The correct answer
https://serverfault.com/questions/44818/how-do-i-set-up-a-shared-directory-on-linux/44831#44831

Answer (score 1):

You should check that the other user is a member of the group. Login as the other user (or switch using su/sudo) and run `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the other user with 'id' command??

## id -a otrheuser

This should show you the user id and group Membership, developer group should be in the list.

What distro are you using?? Because I remember in old distros (like RH9 and previous) you had to run pwconv just after to make a change in /etc/passwd file.